# Outlook Addin - Attachments in Appointment Save Click

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, attachment, appointment

I have an Outlook Addin, doing some code (with attachments) when the user saves an appointment, using Item_Change event.

When I open the Outlook , the Calendar is automatically updated- so Item_Change event fires.

Without debugging, I can see the new attachments in apoointments after the auto update.

In Debug, On Item_Change event appointment.Attachments do **not** contain the new files.

- Can I cause appointment.Attachments to be updated?
- How can I know if Item_Change event fires after auto updtae or because the appointment was saved by the user?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I cause appointment.Attachments to be updated?

You may call the `Save` method.

> How can I know if Item_Change event fires after auto updtae or because the appointment was saved by the user?

The ribbon UI controls can be repurposed so, you will know that users initiated the action. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. Note, you need to override keybord shortcuts too in that case. Read more about that in the [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/09/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) article.

You may also consider handling the [AttachmentAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868540.aspx) event of Outlook items which is fired when an attachment has been added to an item. Or the [BeforeAttachmentAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869219.aspx) event which is fired before an attachment is added and allows to cancel the action.

Comment: I cannot call Save method inside "Item_Change" event - it will cause infinite loop..

Comment: I dont want use the attachmentAdd event . I want to run my code after the user click on "save"

Comment: Do you see the attachment after calling the Save method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the Item_Change event, Call to appointment.Save() does not update appointment.Attachments. 
Call to appointment.Send() **updates** appointment.Attachments **but** cause infinite loop..